# OpenCart ругается на mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, opencart

На всех страницах выводится следующее сообщение:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u275161880/public_html/system/library/db/mysql.php on line 7
```

Что нужно настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` - что с этим делать?

Comment: @titov_andrei идти в мануал)) http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю у Вас версия OpenCart 1.5. Правильнее будет использовать драйвер БД MySQLi. Скачать можно с [каталога расширений](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=13041) . Или версию php можно понизить до 5.3

Comment: так и поступил - понизил версию php